# dom xml parsering problem

Tags: android, android-xml

hi all
i have a xml file and matching with a string value for each element's getTextContent() or getNodeValue(). but the if condition not matching even though the string value is in the xml

String xmlvalue="";
                        xmlvalue=String.valueOf(section1.item(j).getChildNodes().item(k).getTextContent());
    if (xmlvalue=="A"){
      System.out.println("jjj");
     }
i tried following also

String xmlvalue="";

```
   xmlvalue=section1.item(j).getChildNodes().item(k).getTextContent();
         if (xmlvalue=="A"){
             System.out.println("jjj");
          }
```

if condition does not work please help me. but it print all element is in xml. if condition only not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare something's value use .equals >

```
xmlvalue.equals("A")
```

xmlvalue == "A" will check if the two are the same object (which they are clearly not).

And I think writing `"A".equals(xmlvalue)` is preffered to avoid nullpointer in case xmlvalue is null.

The best practise, of course, is to have your "A" in some final field

```
private final static String A = "A"
```

and compare as follows:

```
A.equals(xmlvalue)
```

And the best of all would be using xmlPullParser, since DOM loads the whole xml in memory, which might be critical on such hardware limited devices such as a mobile phone.